# LOESS smoothing - geom_smooth vs() loess()

Tags: r, ggplot2, modeling, derivative, loess

I have some data which I would like to fit with a model. For this example we have been using LOESS smoothing (<1.000 observations). We applied LOESS smoothing using the `geom_smooth()` function from the `ggplot` package. So far, so good.

The next step was to acquire a first derivative of the smoothed curve, and as far as we know this is not possible to extract from `geom_smooth()`. Thus, we sought to manually create our model using `loess()` and use this to extract our first derivative from this.

Strangely however, we observed that the plotted `geom_smooth()` curve is different from the manually constructed `loess()` curve. This can be observed in the figure which is shown underneath; in red the `geom_smooth()` and in orange the `loess()` function.

[image]

If somebody would be interested, a minimal working reproducible example can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/wptmdoorn/07adfe861387169e424baa7e0b733018).

Would somebody be able to pinpoint why the curves are different? Is this because of the optimization settings of both curves? In order to acquire a meaningful derivative we need to ensure that these curves are identical.

Comment: `scale_y_log10(limits = c(1,50000))` removes certain values, which influences the fit done by `ggplot2`, remove it (or change the limits) and both curves are identical.

Comment: Thanks you are totally correct, beetroot. Would there be any way to change the y-scale to a logaritmic format after statistical smoothing? As far as I know (and found), the cartesian coords system does not allow you to change the scaling type on your axes.

Comment: I think the general answer is to use ggplot2 for plotting and to do everything else beforehand. I have no specific answer to your question, maybe someone else does.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72325105/loess-vs-geom-smooth-giving-different-curves