# Loess() vs geom_smooth giving different curves

Tags: r, loess

Wondering how to get a loess() curve to look like the geom_smooth(loess) curve using the same data. I've less than 1000 observations (n=28), and I'm specifying the same span for each.
Here's my code for the two approaches:

```r
loess <- loess(div~prod_no_litter, data=EcoSILY12, span = 0.9) 
summary(loess)
hat <- predict(loess)
plot(div~prod_no_litter, data=EcoSILY12)
lines(EcoSILY12$prod_no_litter[order(EcoSILY12$prod_no_litter)], hat[order(hat)], col="red")

require(ggplot2)

plot1 <- ggplot(EcoSILY12, aes(prod_no_litter,div)) + geom_point() 
plot1 + geom_smooth(method = NULL, span = 0.9)
```

First image is from loess(), second from geom_smooth.

[image: loess() output]

[image: geom_smooth output]

Comment: Can you please share some example data or reproduce the issue using data we have access to? Probably simplest to run `dput(EcoSILY12)` and paste the output into your question.

Comment: @JonSpring Here's the data: structure(list(prod_no_litter = c(671.2, 1399.9, 1608.2, 1184.7167, 
544.7, 523.9333, 354.4333, 292.1, 354.4333, 636.9167, 608.3333, 
231.15, 1886.8333, 516.1333, 474.4833, 1204.4333, 852.9333, 674.2, 
1087.5, 833.6833, 613.3333, 765.8333, 1171.5333, 2582.1667, 585.8, 
201.85, 635.5667, 1120.8333), div = c(16L, 22L, 22L, 18L, 20L, 
18L, 17L, 27L, 20L, 19L, 18L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 16L, 15L, 21L, 19L, 
23L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 11L, 11L, 17L, 12L, 15L, 16L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 73:100)

Answer (score 0):

The way to plot a loess curve (and regression predictions in general) is to pass the `predict` function a new data frame of finely-separated x axis values at which to predict the y value, then plot *these* x, y values. This is how ggplot does it under the hood too.

We can even extract the standard error from the fit to plot the ribbon as a polygon to emulate `geom_smooth`:

```r
loess <- loess(div~prod_no_litter, data=EcoSILY12, span = 0.9) 

hat <- predict(loess, data.frame(prod_no_litter = 400:1280), se = TRUE)

se_xvals <- c(400:1280, 1280:400)
se_yvals <- c(hat$fit - 1.96 * hat$se.fit, rev(hat$fit + 1.96 * hat$se.fit))

plot(div~prod_no_litter, data=EcoSILY12)
polygon(se_xvals, se_yvals, col = "#00000028", border = NA)
lines(400:1280, hat$fit, col="blue")
```

[image]

```r
library(ggplot2)

plot1 <- ggplot(EcoSILY12, aes(prod_no_litter,div)) + geom_point() 
plot1 + geom_smooth(method = NULL, span = 0.9)  
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**Data used**

```r
set.seed(1)

EcoSILY12 <- data.frame(prod_no_litter=rexp(25,0.005 + 400, div = rnorm(25,20,3))
```

Comment: Thanks @allan . Great code, I modified to min and max x values of my data, e.g., 'hat <- predict(loess, data.frame(prod_no_litter = 201:2582), se = TRUE)', (see data in previous comment) and it matches geom_smooth :-), but I get funny looking shading on confi bands.  I'm also trying to add a line at end to calculate R2 which worked before but not now.     'as.numeric(EcoSILY12$div)
is.numeric(EcoSILY12$div)
(r_sq_loess <- cor(EcoSILY12$div, hat)^2)' gives error: Error in cor(EcoSILY12$div, hat) : 'y' must be numeric